# Adjective for thing that can be replaced later because you have better thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just can't seem to remember this word. Please help me, thank you so much

Comment: You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Does the new, better thing already exists (but the old thing hasn't been yet replaced for whatever reasons) or are we predicting that the thing will be replaced in future with a new better thing, once that new better thing is built/discovered?

Comment: Think of the word in Vietnamese, then look up the translation in a dictionary of your choice.

Answer (score 11):

How about [**provisional**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/provisional?q=provisional)?

> Adjective
>
> 1 **arranged for the present time only and likely to be changed in the future** Synonym temporary. *A provisional government.* *Provisional arrangements*
>
> 2 **arranged, but not yet definite.** *The booking is only provisional.*

Answer (score 11):

Another word for a temporary solution is *stopgap*. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stopgap):

> (n) something intended for temporary use until something better or more suitable can be found.

It's given as a noun, but is very commonly used as a noun adjunct, in phrases like "stopgap solution", as can be seen fronm the examples in the dictionary I linked.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using **[replaceable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/replaceable)**

> "Replaceable"
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. able to be replaced.

Usage example:

> ‘These are all temporary
> and **replaceable** items.’

Comment: As a german, who has the word OP is looking for, "replaceable" doesn't at all fit the prompt.
You are completely ignoring the latter part: "because you have a better thing".
A replaceable however does not imply that meaning

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of this term: Placeholder? or Proxy?

Comment: Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can add this detail by using the [edit] link; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: Also, I've edited to delete "Have you ever used Visuwords?". The purpose of EL&U is to provide answers (if at all possible), rather than promoting other non-SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

How about **[obsolete](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolete?q=obsolete)**:

> **obsolete** *adjective*
>
> no longer used because something new has been invented

Another word with pretty similar meanings in IT only is **[deprecated](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deprecate#deprecate__11)**:

> **be deprecated** *(computing)* (of a software feature) to be considered outdated and best avoided, even though you can still use it, usually because it has been replaced with a newer feature
>
> - A number of features have been deprecated in the latest version of the software.

[Here](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/ru_RU/mvvacov.html) you can see a real life example where both words are used together:

> ### mvvacov (deprecated)
>
> computes variance-covariance matrix **This function is obsolete.**

Comment: I don't think these words apply to OP's request for the following reason: Obsolete and deprecated are used when something that used to be relevant or needed is no longer. At the time, though, it was supposed to last. OP specifically requested a word for something that is *not supposed to last*.

Comment: IMHO it's not clear if the word requested by the OP is about something that is already known to have a replacement but still in use as it takes time to replace it (in which case the answer stands) or a word about something that might be replaced one day in future but the replacement does not exist yet (and then it is not the word). I've added a comment to OP's question requesting clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I would say [**stopgap**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stopgap)

> something that you use or do for a short time while you are looking for something better
>
> - The arrangement was only intended as a stopgap.
> - a stopgap measure

Comment: While you've presented this answer perfectly and would normally get an upvote from me, unfortunately you didn't check the other answers. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/468788) provides the same solution, equally well presented, and was posted at least half an hour before yours.

Comment: I did scan the answers when I posted and stopgap wasn't there - now I'm left wondering if either the site just didn't display it to me, or if I just need more coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Approaching this from another angle:

If an item is [**upgradable**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/upgradable) then it has been designed with the intent that it can be replaced when or if a better alternative becomes available - whether or not a "better" version actually exists at the moment.